# Why are these considered Higher Order functions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

In an exam past paper I found online it asks us to rewrite the following higher order functions using list comprehension:

```
hofOne = map (*2) [1,2,3]

hofTwo = filter isSquare randomList
```

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding higher order functions, because I recognize that both the `map` and `filter` functions themselves are higher order functions, but I don't understand how that makes the `hofOne` and `hofTwo` functions higher order when neither of them take a function as a parameter, nor return a function as a result.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: No, you're right. They aren't functions either.

Comment: Maybe the intention was to "Rewrite these applications of higher order functions using list comprehension"

Comment: try defining them in GHCI and then using the :t operator. You will easily see that neither of these are function, in that they have no "arrows" in their type signature. (I haven't tried, but the first looks like `(Num a) => [a]`, while the second depends on the exact types of `isSquare` and `randomList`, but will definitely be of some type `[a]` with some possible restrictions on `a`. No `->` arrows, so they're not functions. (And a higher-order function which takes a function as a parameter will have a bracketed part with one or more arrows in.)

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The [Wikipedia - Higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) article defines higher-order functions as either taking a function in one of its parameters or returning a function as its result. The intention is probably to rewrite the higher-order functions `map` and `filter`, which are higher order functions, as list comprehensions.

Without giving the answer to the question, here are two examples of how to use list comprehensions in the intended style.

```hs
-- map as list comprehension
[doSomething x | x <- [1..10]]

-- filter as list comprehension
[x | x <- [1..10], somethingThatReturnsBool x]
```

For anyone unfamiliar with Haskell list comprehension, take a look at this [article](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension).